# Javascript Object attribute with '-' doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON response in the following format.

```
 {
  "_meta" : {
               "next-person-id" : "1001",
               "totalPersons" : "1000"
            }
 }
```

I am using Angular's `$http` service to retrieve this and trying to access `next-person-id` attribute in javascript like the following,

```
  $http.get(url).then(
        function(response){
              console.log(response._meta.next-person-id);
        }
  );
```

But the `next-person-id` in the response is undefined always. But I'm able to access totalPersons attribute. Is there any problem with getting attributes with '-' character in javascript?

Comment: You can check JavaScript variable name validator from this link https://mothereff.in/js-variables#%E0%B2%A0%5f%E0%B2%A0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
console.log(response._meta['next-person-id']);
```

A possible alternative is to change the keys to use underscores, so that `_meta.next_person_id` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You cant write variables using - as it is also a minus sign.

To solve this, use square bracket notation:

```
console.log(response._meta['next-person-id']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep true, because in `JavaScript` you can use `Latin letters`, `numbers` and `$` `_` symbols for variables or properties.

If you want to use `-`, you should escape it with string quotes.

like this

```
var obj = {
   'next-person-id': 2
}

console.log(obj['next-person-id']); // 2
```

**Explanation:**

In `Global scope` `-` means `minus`. It tries to subtract `person` from `name`. So you will get an error like this:

```
ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

In `JS` you can access to object property in 2 ways

1) Dot nation

```
obj.property
```

2) Square bracket nation

```
obj['property']
```

Here you need to parse string, so as you know in string you can have any symbols except string quote symbol (it will close the string)

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: "because in JavaScript you can use Latin letters, numbers and $ _ symbols for variables or properties" — There are lots of other characters you can use in identifiers.

Comment: "In Global scope - means minus." — Scope is irrelevant. That is what `-` means outside of a string literal.

Comment: @Quentin feel free to edit my answer